# Is Crush's eye color in this panel intentional or a drawing mistake?

Tags: dc, comics, teen-titans

Due to only being half-Czarnian, Crush has eyes that look human, save for the red iris, instead of full-on red eyes with no pupil, like her father Lobo.

[image: Lobo acknowledges crush as his daughter]

After Lex Luthor gifts Lobo with a way to mind-control Crush, however, her eyes turn full red. The only exception, it seems, is in this panel from *Teen Titans* #36 (2019), when she's beating up Robin/Damian Wayne; she's supposed to be under Lobo's control, but her eyes look normal:

[image: Crush beats up Robin and her eyes look normal]

**Is this simply a mistake on the artist's part or is there more to it than meets the eye? If the latter, what gives?**

I'd have thought it could be that Crush genuinely wanted to smash Robin, due to the Djinn situation, but when she did in issue #34, her eyes also turned red - though it's unclear whether it's the anger or mind-control.

[image: Crush with red eyes, ready to hit Robin]